# -App taking 30 seconds to startup after using of new instant run feature in android studio 2.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-2.0

The problem is my application showing white screen for 30 seconds or more than that then launch the launcher activity. I am Using Android studio 2.0 and gradel 2.0.0. Also tried searching any solution for 4 hours but didn't find anything. Even I tried disable the debuggable and run, still app took 30 seconds to launch. My application is becoming big day by day so instant run feature is very helpful for me. Any help will be very highly appreciable.

Check the app without instant run feature - 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.barters.barterstreets

With the instant run feature - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6canhzCkIoCRjBnbU04aHprNGs/view?usp=sharing

Please don't hesitate to ask if any code sample needed, I am confused which part is responsible for the problem so I am not providing any code. Please ask if something needed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: **Instant run** is an Android Studio feature that helps developer quickly deploy the app after making minor changes. It doesn't affect the start up time for a production build.

Comment: @camel I know that dear friend, but unfortunately its happening with me. Thats why I gave link to check.

Comment: `App taking 30 seconds to startup` how is that possible? After **5** seconds your app will be force closed wit an **ANR**.

Comment: @Bob I checked now, both the version working fine.

Comment: Then your problem is solved?

Comment: No still its starting after 30 seconds. Thats my problem.

Comment: I guess you mean that your **emulator** takes 30 seconds to start, not your **app**.

Comment: after that update if i disable InstantRun its taking 10x times to finish GradleBuild,,,,

Comment: @bob when i run app with InstantRun,,,i get white screen  for like 10 seconds and then app launches

Comment: OK, but it's not **your app** the fault. If it was, after only 5 secs it would crash. This is an IDE problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Android Studio 2.3. Beta 1 is currently available, and I'd encourage you to give it a try.

Release announcement: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23beta1isnowavailable Download links: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/

Please let us know your feedback via the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20Instant%20Run%20Bug) if you have any feedback!